# React Redux How pass to action payload target value

Tags: reactjs, redux

i wonder how pass action payload my input value?

In my component i have email input eg.

```
<input type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
 <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.password}/>
```

i have a state in my component:

```
state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    };
```

and i get value with onChange method:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({email: e.target.value});
    }
 password = (e) => {
        this.setState({password: e.target.value})
    }
```

on submit form i have to run some function and here i'm dispatching my action

```
login = () => {
        this.props.userLogin() 
    }
```

in my mapDispatchToProps dispatching my userLogin action. but How i can pass here to action payload this.state.email and this.state.password for using in my action to send api?

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        userLogin: bindActionCreators(userLogin, dispatch),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While dispatching an action you can pass the required values as arguments like

```
login = () => {
    this.props.userLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password); 
}
```

and in the useLogin method in action.js file you can read these arguments like

```
const userLogin = (email, password) => {
   // your userLogin code here
}
```

Comment: okey but how get it in mapDispatchProps and in action.js file

Comment: You don't need to do anything in mapDispatchToProps with the way you are currently using it. and in action.js file, where you have userLogin action you just need `const userLogin = (email, password) => {}`

Comment: thats worked well, i understand the concept. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, props) {
    return {
        userLogin: bindActionCreators(props.loginInfo, dispatch),
    }
}
```

and you can call it in this way:

```js
login = () => {
        this.props.userLogin(this.state);
        // state will habe password and username as {username, password}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass state object in action creator and received in action creator as in argument where you received.

Comment: How i can do that?

Comment: where you calling action dispatcher, show your complete component

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem everything work well with my first approach. Here problem was setting state in component with constructor. When i remove constructor everything worked.